# Ability to create forms for each node in Drupal 7

Tags: flags, rating, entities

I am creating articles in which I want to ask, on each article, that whether the it was helpful to read or not.

The user would have two option boxes:-

© Yes

© No

One of these will be selected and the form should be submitted through JQuery. It should be recorded with each node so that we would also know how many total users found this helpful too?

Any idea how would I achieve that?

I wish it could be achieved through Flags or Rating but I haven't been able to do so.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much the use case of the [Rate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/Rate). By using a *custom widget*, you can present arbitrary label/value options for the user to select (e.g. Yes = +1 / No = -1).

The only difference is that they're presented as hyperlinks instead of radio selects. With some front-end customization, you probably could change that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shawn is correct.

However if you're absolutely *set* on using form components and you don't want to mess with the front-end as suggested, you could try using [Webform AJAX](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) to add a form to your page that is submitted via AJAX (which is what I think you meant by "submitted through jQuery"?).

You can then use jQuery to click the submit button when they've made a choice.  Even hide the submit button with CSS, it should still work.